# How to add page header without first page itext 7

Tags: c#, itext7

I created document using pdfHTMl in Text 7. I want to add page header for every pages without first page. I used PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE event. But it applies for every pages with first page. How to remove page header from the first page?
Thank You.

Comment: Check for the page number in your event handler. If the page number is 1, don't add the header. Show us your code, that will make is easier for us to explain what you're overlooking.

Comment: For some inspiration concerning dynamic headers, you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50254294/1729265) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50486934/1729265). If you want more specific help, you should share your current pivotal code (as @Bruno has already said).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of an event handler that adds a header:

```
protected class MyEventHandler implements IEventHandler {

    PdfFont helvetica;

    public MyEventHandler() throws IOException {
        helvetica = PdfFontFactory.createFont();
    }

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
        int pageNumber = pdfDoc.getPageNumber(page);
        if (pageNumber == 1) return;
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
        pdfCanvas.beginText()
            .setFontAndSize(helvetica, 9)
            .moveText(pageSize.getWidth() / 2 - 30, pageSize.getTop() - 20)
            .showText("THIS IS A HEADER!")
            .endText();
        pdfCanvas.release();
    }
}
```

Because of the `if (pageNumber == 1) return;` there won't be any header added. so there's no need to remove the header. As you can see in the screen shot, there is no header on page one, but a header on each following page.

[image]